# Finding the quadruplet when the sum of their reciprocals are given

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If a,b,c,d are positive integers such that a, b, c,d are in ascending order and no two of them are equal and 1/a + 1/b + 1/c + 1/d = 11/6 then find d-b.
Whenever I encounter these types of question, I just simply do the hit-and trial method (for e.g. assumming a=1,b=2, and then checking whether there is a pair for it or not).But sometimes I do not get the answer like in this one. Can someone give me a solution that is more accurate rather than guessing the numbers?

Comment: I did 11/6=1+5/6=1+1/2+1/3=1/2+1/2+1/2+1/3. So, maybe if you try to decompose your given fraction instead of trying to put values to the variables is better to find the answer?

Comment: But no two of the numbers are to be equal

Comment: Oh, I didn't read that. I'll think about this.

Answer (score 1):

**Technical part to discard some cases (you may ommit this)**

Note that such solution satisfies $6(bcd+acd+abd+abc)=11abcd$. You can check that $a|6bcd$,$b|6acd$,$c|6abd$,$d|6abc$, (this gives you some restrictions for $a,b,c,d$ that maybe useful when discarding cases.) For instance, this tells you that there are no multiples of $5$ between $a,b,c,d$. Because, if there is a multiple of $5$, then this number should divide the product of the other three numbers, which implies that there is other multiple of $5$. We would have at least two multiples of $5$, so your sum is at most $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{10}<1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{11}{6}$.

**Proof that $a=1$, $b=2$**

If $a>1$, you have $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}<11/6.$$
A contradiction. So, $a=1$.

Now your problem becomes $$\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}=5/6$$

Doing a similar approach, if $b>2$, we have $$\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\leq 1/3+1/4+1/5<5/6$$
So, $b=2$.

**Main part, how to solve an equation of the form 1/c+1/d=1/n**

Now your problem becomes $$\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}=\frac{1}{3}$$ i.e. $$3(d+c)=cd,$$ so one of them ($c$ or $d$) has to be a multiple of $3$. Let's drop the condition of $c<d$, and let's just assume $c\neq d$ for simplicity (if we find a solution with $d<c$, then just interchange $c,d$).

So, WLOG, $c=3k$. Then $3k+d=kd$. Looking mod $d$ and mod $k$ we see that $d|3k$ and $k|d$. So, we have only two options $d=k$ or $d=3k$. The second case is discarded, since that case gives us $c=d$.

So, we are left with $d=k$, which gives us $3k+k=k^2$, it's easy to solve that $k=4$. So, the solution is $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}=1/3$.

**Answer:**

We conclude that (the only) solution is $$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}=\frac{11}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $a=2$ the maximum the sum can be is $\frac 12+\frac 13+\frac 14+\frac 15=\frac{77}{60}$, which is too small, so $a=1$.
Similarly, if $b=3$ the maximum is $\frac 11+\frac 13+\frac 14+\frac 15=\frac{107}{60}$, which is too small, so $b=2$.
Now we have $$\frac 11+\frac 12+\frac 1c+\frac 1d=\frac {11}6\\\frac 1c+\frac 1d=\frac 13$$
We must have $c \gt 3$ and $c\ge 6$ will leave the sum too small, which leaves only $4,5$ to try.

Alternately, you might know the identity
$$\frac 1{n+1}+\frac 1{n(n+1)}=\frac 1n$$
and be able to make $c=4,d=12$ from that.